# Autodesk derivative urn missing after translating from .rvt to .svf

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am doing the following steps to convert an .rvt file into .svf

1. Authenticate
2. upload .rvt file
3. translate it to .svf (with modelderivative/v2/designdata/job)
4. with the response check the job complete by checking the manifest (/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/manifest)
5. once the job is complete (from manifest status), the response I get does not contain derivatives urns
   Link to the complete manifest response : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByrHSB-f7jP3TXhHYVQtOEUyM2c/view?usp=sharing

Sample response: the derivative urn is missing

```
class ManifestDerivative {
    name: autodesk.rvt
    hasThumbnail: true
    outputType: svf
    progress: complete
    status: success
    children: [class ManifestChildren {
        type: geometry
        role: 2d
        name: 03.51 - Detail V.01
        hasThumbnail: true
        mime: null
        urn: null
        progress: complete
        status: success
        resolution: []
        modelGUID: null
        objectIds: []
        messages: null
    }, class ManifestChildren {
        type: geometry
        role: 2
        ....
```

I want to know whether the urn returned by this response manifest is enough for downloading the bubble or there is something that I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

The manifest is enough to download svf, however it is not a straightforward workflow, take a look at my recent blog post: [Forge SVF Extractor in Node.js](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs) and at this project that does the extraction for you: [https://extract.autodesk.io](https://extract.autodesk.io/). You can find the source [there](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but, I am a java developer and not that comfortable with the java script.  I am using the autodesk java sdk.

Comment: I have tried to understand the java script project, but what I observe is urn and mime type is null in my case, were as that is expected to have values.

Comment: There is no SDK methods that can help you with that workflow except getManifest. Unfortunately we don't have a Java version of that code ... Do you mean that urn is missing from the manifest response returned by the API? In which case you could log an issue against the Java SDK: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-java-client

Comment: Thank you @Philippe, will log an issue in the Java SDK